# Change the local setting to enable sed work correctly, but why?

Tags: bash, sed, local

The following is a bash file I wrote to convert all C++ style(//) comments in a C file to C style(/**/).

```
#!/bin/bash
lang=`echo $LANG`
# It's necessary to change the local setting. I don't know why.
export LANG=C
# Can comment the following statement if there is not dos2unix command.
dos2unix -q $1
sed -i -e 's;^\([[:blank:]]*\)//\(.*\);\1/* \2 */;' $1
export LANG=$lang
```

It works. But I found a problem I cannot explain. In default, my local setting is en_US.UTF-8. And in my C code, there are comments written in Chinese, such as

```
// some english 一些中文注释
```

If I don't change the local setting, i.e., do not run the statement *export LANG=C*, I'll get

```
/* some english */一些中文注释
```

instead of

```
/* some english 一些中文注释*/
```

I don't know why. I just find a solution by try and error.

---

After read Jonathan Leffler's answer, I think I've make some mistake leading to some misunderstand. In the question, those Chinese words were inputed in Google Chrome and were not the actual words in my C file. 一些中文注释 just means *some Chinese comments*.

Now I inputed *// some english 一些中文注释* in Visual C++ 6.0 in Windows XP, and copied the c file to Debian. Then I just run *sed -i -e 's;^([[:blank:]]*)//(.*);\1/* \2 */;' $1* and got

```
/* some english 一些 */中文注释
```

I think it's different character coding(GB18030, GBK, UTF-8?) cause the different results.

The following is my results gotten on Debian

```
~/sandbox$ uname -a
Linux xyt-dev 2.6.30-1-686 #1 SMP Sat Aug 15 19:11:58 UTC 2009 i686 GNU/Linux
~/sandbox$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
~/sandbox$ cat tt.c | od -c -t x1
0000000   /   /       s   o   m   e       e   n   g   l   i   s   h    
         2f  2f  20  73  6f  6d  65  20  65  6e  67  6c  69  73  68  20
0000020 322 273 320 251 326 320 316 304 327 242 312 315
         d2  bb  d0  a9  d6  d0  ce  c4  d7  a2  ca  cd
0000034
~/sandbox$ ./convert_comment_style_cpp2c.sh tt.c
~/sandbox$ cat tt.c | od -c -t x1
0000000   /   *           s   o   m   e       e   n   g   l   i   s   h
         2f  2a  20  20  73  6f  6d  65  20  65  6e  67  6c  69  73  68
0000020     322 273 320 251       *   / 326 320 316 304 327 242 312 315
         20  d2  bb  d0  a9  20  2a  2f  d6  d0  ce  c4  d7  a2  ca  cd
0000040
~/sandbox$
```

I think these Chinese Character encoding with 2 byte(Unicode).

There are another example:

```
~/sandbox$ cat tt.c | od -c -t x1
0000000   /   /       I   n   W   i   n   d   o   w   :     250 250   ?
         2f  2f  20  49  6e  57  69  6e  64  6f  77  3a  20  a8  a8  3f
0000020   1   ?
         31  3f
0000022
~/sandbox$ ./convert_comment_style_cpp2c.sh tt.c
~/sandbox$ cat tt.c | od -c -t x1
0000000   /   *           I   n   W   i   n   d   o   w   :           *
         2f  2a  20  20  49  6e  57  69  6e  64  6f  77  3a  20  20  2a
0000020   / 250 250   ?   1   ?
         2f  a8  a8  3f  31  3f
```

Comment: Which platform are you working on?  Your `sed` script works fine on MacOS X without changing locale.  The Linux terminal was less happy with the Chinese characters, but it is not setup to use UTF-8. Moreover, a hex dump of the string that it did get contained a zero byte 0x00 where the Chinese started, which might lead to the confusion.  The Mac did not show 0x00; it showed 0x80.  (I note that your regex adds a space before the comment text if it starts `// with a space`.)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I tested on Debian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which platform are you working on?  Your `sed` script works fine on MacOS X without changing locale.  The Linux terminal was less happy with the Chinese characters, but it is not setup to use UTF-8. Moreover, a hex dump of the string that it did get contained a zero byte 0x00 where the Chinese started, which might lead to the confusion.  (I note that your regex adds a space before the comment text if it starts `// with a space`.)

#### MacOS X (10.6.8)

The 'odx' command use is a hex-dump program.

```
$ echo "// some english 一些中文注释" > x3.utf8
$ odx x3.utf8
0x0000: 2F 2F 20 73 6F 6D 65 20 65 6E 67 6C 69 73 68 20   // some english 
0x0010: E4 B8 80 E4 BA 9B E4 B8 AD E6 96 87 E6 B3 A8 E9   ................
0x0020: 87 8A 0A                                          ...
0x0023:
$ utf8-unicode x3.utf8
0x2F = U+002F
0x2F = U+002F
0x20 = U+0020
0x73 = U+0073
0x6F = U+006F
0x6D = U+006D
0x65 = U+0065
0x20 = U+0020
0x65 = U+0065
0x6E = U+006E
0x67 = U+0067
0x6C = U+006C
0x69 = U+0069
0x73 = U+0073
0x68 = U+0068
0x20 = U+0020
0xE4 0xB8 0x80 = U+4E00
0xE4 0xBA 0x9B = U+4E9B
0xE4 0xB8 0xAD = U+4E2D
0xE6 0x96 0x87 = U+6587
0xE6 0xB3 0xA8 = U+6CE8
0xE9 0x87 0x8A = U+91CA
0x0A = U+000A
$ sed 's;^\([[:blank:]]*\)//\(.*\);\1/* \2 */;' x3.utf8
/*  some english 一些中文注释 */
$
```

All of which looks clean and tidy.

#### Linux (RHEL 5)

I copied the `x3.utf8` file to a Linux box, and dumped it.  Then I ran the `sed` script on it, and all seemed OK:

```
$ odx x3.utf8
0x0000: 2F 2F 20 73 6F 6D 65 20 65 6E 67 6C 69 73 68 20   // some english 
0x0010: E4 B8 80 E4 BA 9B E4 B8 AD E6 96 87 E6 B3 A8 E9   ................
0x0020: 87 8A 0A                                          ...
0x0023:
$ sed 's;^\([[:blank:]]*\)//\(.*\);\1/* \2 */;' x3.utf8 | odx
0x0000: 2F 2A 20 20 73 6F 6D 65 20 65 6E 67 6C 69 73 68   /*  some english
0x0010: 20 E4 B8 80 E4 BA 9B E4 B8 AD E6 96 87 E6 B3 A8    ...............
0x0020: E9 87 8A 20 2A 2F 0A                              ... */.
0x0027:
$
```

So far, so good.  I also tried:

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$ echo $LC_CTYPE

$ env | grep LC_
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
$ cat x3.utf8
// some english 一些中文注释
$ echo $(<x3.utf8)
// some english 一些中文注释
$ sed 's;^\([[:blank:]]*\)//\(.*\);\1/* \2 */;' x3.utf8      
/*  some english 一些中文注释 */
$
```

So, the terminal is nominally working in UTF-8 after all, and it certainly seems display the data OK.

However, if I echo the string at the terminal, it gets into a tizzy.  When I cut'n'pasted the string to the Linux terminal, it said:

```
$ echo "// some english d8d^G:
> "
// some english d8d:

$
```

and beeped.

```
$ echo "// some english d8d^G:
> " | odx
0x0000: 2F 2F 20 73 6F 6D 65 20 65 6E 67 6C 69 73 68 20   // some english 
0x0010: 64 38 64 07 3A 0A 0A                              d8d.:..
0x0017:
$
```

I'm not quite sure what to make of that.  I think it means that something in the input side of `bash` is having some problems, but I'm not quite sure.  I also am getting slightly inconsistent results.  The first time I tried it, I got:

```
$ cat > xxx
's;^\([[:blank:]]*\)//\(.*\);\1/* \2 */;'
// some english d8^@d:^[d8-f^Gf3(i^G

$ odx xxx
0x0000: 27 73 3B 5E 5C 28 5B 5B 3A 62 6C 61 6E 6B 3A 5D   's;^\([[:blank:]
0x0010: 5D 2A 5C 29 2F 2F 5C 28 2E 2A 5C 29 3B 5C 31 2F   ]*\)//\(.*\);\1/
0x0020: 2A 20 5C 32 20 2A 2F 3B 27 0A 2F 2F 20 73 6F 6D   * \2 */;'.// som
0x0030: 65 20 65 6E 67 6C 69 73 68 20 64 38 00 64 3A 1B   e english d8.d:.
0x0040: 64 38 2D 66 07 66 33 28 69 07 0A 0A               d8-f.f3(i...
0x004C:
$
```

And in that hex dump, you can see a 0x00 byte (offset 0x003C).  That appears at the position where you got the end comment, and a null there could confuse `sed`; but the whole input is such a mess it is hard to know what to make of it.

Comment: thanks for sharing your testing methodologies. This is awesome!

Comment: @shellter: For the Linux, I was telnet'd from my Mac via a VPN to a machine 1800 miles from where I'm sitting (probably via an access point about 3000 miles from where I'm sitting).  So, part of the display was my Mac terminal; I have TERM=xterm-color set on Linux, and a recompiled copy of the terminfo entry from the Mac.  There's a lot of stuff that could be going wrong there...  I'm sorry I don't have a definitive answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's the correct answer...

The GNU regular expression library (regex) doesn't match everything when you put a `.` in your expression. Yup, I know how braindead that sounds.

The problem comes from the word "character", now reasonable people will say that everything that's in the input file for sed is characters. And even in your case they are perfectly correct. But regex has been programmed to required that the input be perfectly correctly formatted characters of the current locale character set (UTF-8) if they're correctly formatted characters for the Windows character set (UTF-16) they're not "characters".

So as `.` only matches "characters" it doesn't match your characters.

If you used the regex `//.*$`, ie: pinned it to the end of the line it wouldn't match at all because there's something that's not a "character" between the `//` and the end of the line.

And no you can't do anything like `//\(.\|[^.]\)*$`, it's just impossible to match those characters without switching to the C locale.

This will also, sometimes, destroy 8-bit transparency; ie: a binary piped through sed will get corrupted even if no changes are made.

Fortunately the C locale still uses the reasonable interpretation so anything that's not a perfectly correctly formatted ASCII-68 character is still a "character".